# Setting the legend size in ol.legend.Legend()

Tags: legend, default

I'm working in a print map using legend with ol-ext library. It's working fine but when I see the legend in the corner it's not getting in the original size.

How can i use the legend in default size?

My code is

```js
var legend = new ol.legend.Legend({ 
   title: 'Legend', 
   margin: 2,
   items: [
       {
           title: '', 
           typeGeom: 'Point', 
           style: new ol.style.Style({ 
               image: new ol.style.Icon({ 
               src: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?Service=WMS&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&LAYER='+xx+'',
               crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
               // width:  500,
               // Enable print
               })
            })
        }
    ]
});
            
var legendCtrl = new ol.control.Legend({ legend: legend });
map.addControl(legendCtrl);
```

Comment: Welcome to the site @manoj-semwal please check your tags, as geoext and openlayers is not the same

Comment: Kindly help to print only image in item: how can i ?